# How to generate "x(close symbol)" in anchor tag?

Tags: html

How to print X (close symbol) in html page using `<a>` ?

```
<a href = "" >X</a>

<a href = "" >X</a>
```

I want X (close symbol) in HTML page using anchor tag

Comment: <a href = "#">X</a>

Answer (score 1):

X shape symbol-  ×

```
<a href = "" > &times;</a>
```

Cross shape close symbol - ✖

```
<a href = "" >&#x2716;</a>
```

Bold cross shape close symbol :❌

```
<a href = "" >&#x274c;</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HTML entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) `&times;` (×) which is commonly used to represent the close symbol/icon. You can adjust the size of the icon by changing the `font-size` style in CSS and remove the underline using `text-decoration`:

```css
.close {
  font-size: 30px; /* adjust icon size */
  text-decoration: none; /* remove underline from link */
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
```